# add a line item with custom fields to an order programatically

Tags: webforms, commerce

On drupal7, I use commerce webform module to allow users to add products by checking checkboxes. What i want to do is to add a custom product (its price is O$) to put on it custom fields whose values are submitted by the commerce webform. It's a way to add informations on the order and to have it displayed on the line items in the cart. So i create a custom module with a hook_form_alter. In my webform, i have three components:
- A productfields (with a list of available products): the user can do a multiple selection (to select several products of the same type)
- A field called imagethumb (a image field)
- A field called infobulle (a text field)
What i want to do is to get the values of the two fields (that is simple), and add them to the new line item, so they can be displayed in the cart.
Here is my code:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_form_alter().
*/
function custom_webform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add validation for a particular Webform node:
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_15') {

// Add the submit handler after the existing Webform submit handler,
// but before the second Webform handler. Pop off the first one and add
// ours second.
$first = array_shift($form['#submit']);
array_unshift($form['#submit'], $first, 'custom_webform_submit_15');
  }
}
/**
* Submit handler for Webform ID #15.
*/
function custom_webform_submit_15(&$form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $uid = $user->uid;
  $product_id = 7;

  //load the order
  $order = commerce_cart_order_load($uid);

  //load the product
  $product = commerce_product_load($product_id);// On charge le produit


  // Create a line item with quantity 1 and this product.
  $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, $order->order_id);

  //get the form values that we need

  $nid = $form_state['values']['details']['nid'];
  $sid = $form_state['values']['details']['sid'];
  $imagethumb = $form_state['values']['submitted_tree']['image_thumb'];
  $infobulle = $form_state['values']['submitted_tree']['info_bulle'];


  //create a wrapper
  $line_item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $line_item, $info);

  //and here is the problem
  $line_item_wrapper->commerce_webform_nid = $nid;
  $line_item_wrapper->commerce_webform_sid = $sid;
  $line_item_wrapper->field_imagethumb = $imagethumb;
  $line_item_wrapper->field_infobulle = $infobulle;

  // Save the line item to get its ID.
  commerce_line_item_save($line_item);

  // Add the line item to the order using the wrapper.
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;

  // Save the order again to update its line item reference field.
  commerce_order_save($order);
```

And this is what i have:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException : Unknown data property
>   commerce_webform_nid. dans EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo()
>   (ligne 339 dans
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc).

I have the same thing when i replace 'commerce_webform_nid' by simply 'nid' and the script stop. If i delete the line with 'commerce_webform_nid', then the exception is on the line after. So my question is: How can i achieve that? How can i assign the values that i getted to properties of the newly added line item? Thanks.
PS: When i delete the lines where there is the problem, the script works, and there is a new line item in the cart, but obviously without the values that i want to get.